# What is the SQL Server equivalent of MySQL's utf8mb4 character set?

Tags: sql-server, migration, collation, character-set, unicode

We have some web applications based on databases using `utf8mb4` as character set and `utf8mb4_Standard` as collation.

[image: MYSQL]

We saw that we can use any character we want with this setting.

In SQL Server Express the situation is not very clear to me.

When I switch to `Standard` it chooses the `Latin1_General_CI_AS` collation.

But I do not know which character encoding this is and how it would affect the scenario if we would like to take over some data from `utf7mb8` MySQL tables into SQL Server.

[image]

When I look into the datatype definition in SQL Server, I can see that there are Unicode and non Unicode types. So I am wondering if the collation actually has impact into how it is stored:

[image]

It seems that if you use `nchar`, `nvarchar` or `nvarchar(max)` you are on the safe side as you use UTF-16.

But, what does the collation `Latin1_General_CI_AS` mean?

Especially how would this behave if you had Chinese characters, for example?

Comment: The `nchar/nvarchar` types are **Unicode** and thus capable of handling Chinese, Japanese, Cyrillic, Arabic, Hebrew etc. characters. `char/varchar` are **not** Unicode, and thus very limited in their support for non-Latin alphabets. If you need far eastern characters, use `nvarchar` for your strings. Drawback: `nvarchar` always uses **2 bytes per character** for its encoding

Comment: @marc_s haven't they added support for Supplementary characters (that can use (2 or) 4 bytes per character)?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ **1)** Supplementary Characters are always 4 bytes, both in UTF-16 and UTF-8. **2)** `NVARCHAR`, `NCHAR`, and `NTEXT` have always been able to store them (not 100% sure about SQL Server < 2000, but I'm guessing that it was the same then as well). UCS-2 always included the 2048 surrogate code points, it just never defined their combinations as being separate code points. **3)** Displaying them is a font, not SQL Server, issue. **4)** "support" is version >= 90 collations giving them simple sort weights & `_SC` collations allowing built-in functions to see them as a single entities.

Comment: @marc_s To be clear: UTF-16 is 2 bytes per code _unit_. BMP code _points_ are a single code unit, while Supplementary Character code points are 2 code units. Please also see my comment above which clarifies a few additional points regarding Supplementary Characters.

Answer (score 6):

First: the particular "edition" of SQL Server (i.e. Express, Standard, Enterprise, etc) does not matter. All editions for a particular version will behave the same.

> When I switch to "Standard" it chooses the `Latin1_General_CI_AS` collation.

Well, that is better than a collation starting with `SQL_`, but still not ideal. If you are using SQL Server 2008 or newer, then you should be using a version 100 collation (or a  version 140 collation IF using SQL Server 2017 or newer *and* specifying a Japanese collation). AND, if using SQL Server 2012 or newer, then you should be using a collation that supports supplementary characters, which means your choices are:

- version 100 collations with names ending in `_SC`, or
- version 140 collations (only Japanese collations have a version 140 set, but none of these end in `_SC` since supplementary character support is built into all version 140 collations)

In your case, most likely you want: `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC`

Technically speaking, the closest equivalent to `utf8mb4_general_ci` (there is no `utf8mb4_Standard`, and your screen shot even shows `utf8mb4_general_ci`) is `Latin1_General_CI_AI`. Reason being:

- The `utf8mb4` character set allows you to store supplementary characters (which `NVARCHAR` also does, regardless of collation),
- the `general` part of the MySQL collation means that supplementary characters all have the same weight. This pre-level 100 SQL Server collation is similar in that all supplementary characters have the same weight, it's just that they have no weight at all.
- the `ci` in the MySQL collation implies `ai` since `as` isn't specified.

Still, you want to stick with: `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC`.

> I do not know which character encoding this is and how it would affect the scenario if we would like to take over some data from `utf7mb8` MySQL tables into SQL Server.

The encoding is determined by a combination of the datatype and the collation:

- `NVARCHAR` (and `NCHAR` / `NTEXT`) is *always* UTF-16 LE (Little Endian).
- `VARCHAR` (and `CHAR` / `TEXT`) is *always* an 8-bit encoding, the specific encoding determined by the code page associated with the collation being used.

That said, it shouldn't matter what the source encoding is as long as the destination encoding can handle all of the incoming characters (and behave in a similar manner, of course, which is where the culture and sensitivities come in). Assuming you will be storing everything in `NVARCHAR` (maybe occasionally `NCHAR`, but never `NTEXT` as that has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005), then the data transfer tool will handle any necessary conversions.

> what does the collation `Latin1_General_CI_AS` mean?

It means:

- Because the name does not start with `SQL_`, this is a Windows collation, not a SQL Server collation (and this is a good thing as the SQL Server collations — those starting with `SQL_` — are mainly for pre-SQL Server 2000 compatibility, although quite unfortunately `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` is very common due to it being the default when installing on an OS using US English as its language)
- `Latin1_General` is the culture / locale.

  - For `NVARCHAR` data this determines the linguistic rules used for sorting and comparison.
  - For `VARCHAR` data this determines the:

    - linguistic rules used for sorting and comparison.
    - code page used to encode the characters. For example, `Latin1_General` collations use code page 1252, `Hebrew` collations use code page 1255, and so on.
- `{version}`, while not present in this collation name, refers to the SQL Server version in which the collation was introduced (for the most part). Windows collations with no version number in the name are version `80` (meaning SQL Server 2000 as that is version 8.0). Not all versions of SQL Server come with new collations, so there are gaps in the version numbers. There are some that are `90` (for SQL Server 2005, which is version 9.0), most are `100` (for SQL Server 2008, version 10.0), and a small set has `140` (for SQL Server 2017, version 14.0).

  I said "for the most part" because the collations ending in `_SC` were introduced in SQL Server 2012 (version 11.0), but the underlying data wasn't new, they merely added support for supplementary characters for the built-in functions. So, those endings exist for version `90` and `100` collations, but only starting in SQL Server 2012.
- Next you have the sensitivities, that can be in any combination of the following, but always specified in this order:

  - `CS` = case-sensitive or `CI` = case-insensitive
  - `AS` = accent-sensitive or `AI` = accent-insensitive
  - `KS` = Kana type-sensitive or missing = Kana type-insensitive
  - `WS` = width-sensitive or missing = width insensitive
  - `VSS` = variation selector sensitive (only available in the version 140 collations) or missing = variation selector insensitive
- Optional last piece:

  - `_SC` at the end means "Supplementary Character support". The "support" only affects how the built-in functions interpret surrogate pairs (which are how supplementary characters are encoded in UTF-16). Without `_SC` at the end (or `_140_` in the middle), built-in functions don't see a single supplementary character, but instead see two meaningless code points that make up the surrogate pair. This ending can be added to any non-binary, version 90 or 100 collation.
  - `_BIN` or `_BIN2` at the end means "binary" sorting and comparison. Data is still stored the same, but there are no linguistic rules. This ending is never combined with any of the 5 sensitivities or `_SC`. `_BIN` is the older style, and `_BIN2` is the newer, more accurate style. If using SQL Server 2005 or newer, use `_BIN2`. For details on the differences between `_BIN` and `_BIN2`, please see: [Differences Between the Various Binary Collations (Cultures, Versions, and BIN vs BIN2)](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2019/03/13/differences-between-the-various-binary-collations-cultures-versions-and-bin-vs-bin2/).
  - `_UTF8` is a new option as of SQL Server 2019. It's an 8-bit encoding that allows for Unicode data to be stored in `VARCHAR` and `CHAR` datatypes (but not the deprecated `TEXT` datatype). This option can only be used on collations that support supplementary characters (i.e. version 90 or 100 collations with `_SC` in their name, and version 140 collations). There is also a single binary `_UTF8` collation (`_BIN2`, not `_BIN`).

    **PLEASE NOTE:** UTF-8 was designed / created for compatibility with environments / code that are set up for 8-bit encodings yet want to support Unicode. Even though there are a few scenarios where UTF-8 can provide up to 50% space savings as compared to `NVARCHAR`, that is a side-effect and has a cost of a slight hit to performance in many / most operations. If you need this for compatibility, then the cost is acceptable. If you want this for space-savings, you had better test, and TEST AGAIN. Testing includes all functionality, and more than just a few rows of data. Be warned that UTF-8 collations work best when ALL columns, and the database itself, are using `VARCHAR` data (columns, variables, string literals) with a `_UTF8` collation. This is the natural state for anyone using this for compatibility, but not for those hoping to use it for space-savings. Be careful when mixing VARCHAR data using a `_UTF8` collation with either `VARCHAR` data using non-`_UTF8` collations or `NVARCHAR` data, as you might experience odd behavior / data loss. For more details on the new UTF-8 collations, please see: [Native UTF-8 Support in SQL Server 2019: Savior or False Prophet?](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/09/28/native-utf-8-support-in-sql-server-2019-savior-false-prophet-or-both/)

> Especially how would this behave if you had Chinese characters, for example?

- If you are storing those characters in a `VARCHAR` column or variable, you would most likely lose those characters as they get converted to `?`. There are a few Chinese locale collations that use a double-byte character set (DBCS) for `VARCHAR` that can store more than 256 different characters, but it's still not even close to what is available in Unicode.
- If you are storing those characters in an `NVARCHAR` column or variable, there would be no data loss. However, with the `Latin1_General` culture / locale (Western European / US English), you won't get any Chinese-specific linguistic rules, so sorting and comparisons of the Chinese characters (anything different than what is in the default definition) will likely not behave as would be appropriate for that language. In which case you simply use a Chinese collation, version 100, and with `_SC` in the name.

Comment: Great answer, it could be a superlative answer could you add a paragraph on the most appropriate collation types (best practice) to use on "both ends" of the MSSQL and MySQL equation, for both cases of mixed varchar/nvarchar tables and pure nvarchar. e.g. MSSQL's default `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` <--> MySQL default `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` will have no issues transferring **to** MySQL, but not so good in the reverse case.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is way old. but having a similar issue...

```
But what does the collation Latin1_General_CI_AS mean, then?
```

> The remaining codes in each collation name (such as _CS_AI_WS_SC) indicate the options preconfigured on the collation. For example, CI means case-insensitive and AS means accent-sensitive. The description column shows what the option codes mean. For more detailed information, see the Microsoft article [“Collation and Unicode Support.”](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-2017) ~ pulled from [RedGate](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-development/questions-sql-server-collations-shy-ask/#post-70501-_Toc479001442)

If you need info on the breakdown to your question straight [from microsoft, check this out.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-2017#Collation_Defn)

Although there isn't a `MySQL` alternative for `UTF8MB4` you can use emojis [as listed here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33938445/1896134)

Please checkout ['How do I set a SQL Server Unicode / NVARCHAR string to an emoji or Supplementary Character?'](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/139568/27509) for a very detailed info on encodings.

Here is some more info of [MSSQL Collations 2017.](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/10/16/all-new-collations-in-sql-server-2017-implicitly-support-supplementary-characters/)

**[Lastly, Please read this.](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)** as this is a nice version of history broken down from a perspective.